# Dynamic variable in XSLT for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to take the question and only its options (those with their code attribute beginning with the question code). For example: if I've got a question T1Q1, I want to retrieve only the options T1Q1_1, T1Q1_2, and so on.

I made a for-each loop. I wanted to iterate over every question, take its code, and then iterate again on all the options whose code begins with the question code characters. But I don't know how to do that.

**XML:**

```
<question code="T1Q1">Which encoding did you use?</question>
<option code="T1Q1_1">ISO-8859-1</option>
<option code="T1Q1_2">UTF-8</option>
<option code="T1Q1_3">Other</option>

<question code="T1Q2">Which blabla did you blabla?</question>
<option code="T1Q2_1">Absurdanipal</option>
<option code="T1Q2_2">Fantasmagoric</option>
<option code="T1Q2_3">Other</option>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="pollns:question">
<xsl:value-of select="@code"/><br/>
  <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::pollns:option[starts-with(@code,'T1Q1')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><br />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

As you can see, I wrote `starts-with(@code, 'T1Q1')`. I want to replace that T1Q1 with a dynamic variable or something similar that changes for each question.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got the solution.

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="pollns:question">
  <xsl:variable name="questionCode" select="@code"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="@code"/><br/>
     <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::pollns:option[starts-with(@code,$questionCode)]">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/><br />
     </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```